# Detect which Tab was selected on TabBarController from inside a TableViewController - Code Reuse

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2

I have an application which has 5 tabs on a TabBarController. For simplicity sake lets say they are Tab A, B, C, D, and E. Each tab takes the user to a TableViewController which is embedded in a Navigation controller. Each tab also has its own specific .h and .m files. The code for the most part is very similar between the 5 tabs. I want to do away with these 5 sets of class files and just use 1 set. This will make it much easier for me to make changes to the application (in 1 place instead of 5 places). How can I detect in the single implementation file which tab was selected? Once I know that I can put logic in place to render the tableview specifically for which tab was selected...

Another thing I should mention is that I need to detect the selected Tab in the TableViewController. The TabBarController is the point of entry for the application and I do not have a TabBarController subclass.

I tried this code in the TableViewController however it does not get accessed and/or used.

in .h file:

```
@interface MyController : UITableViewController <UITabBarDelegate>
```

in .m file:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    //NSLog(@"selectedIndex: %d", self.tabBarController.selectedIndex);

    NSLog(@"didSelectItem: %d", item.tag);
}
```

Comment: Try putting the similar code in a class which you then subclass five times for your A, B, C, D and E VCs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy, You already have the solution!

> **tabBarController**
>
> A parent or ancestor that is a tab bar controller.
>   (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UITabBarController *tabBarController
>
> Discussion If the receiver is added to a tab bar controller, this property is the tab bar controller. If the receiver’s
>   navigation controller is added to a tab bar controller, this property
>   is the navigation controller’s tab bar controller. If no tab bar is
>   present or the receiver is a modal view, this property is nil.

That means that any viewController you add to a tab bar controller has this property filled in by the system.

Then in the view controller you want for the tab you implement viewWillAppear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;
    switch (selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
            //configure me
            break;
        case 1:
            //configure me differently!!
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In light of the comments this property of tabBarController doesn't seem to be reliable.

The problem you describe sounds like something that could solved by subclassing. Make a subclass of UIViewController for the code in common with each tab and then subclass your subclass for each tabs viewController to make modifications unique to the tab.

Alternatively you could load each tab with the same class but a different xib. You can set properties on your view controller in the "user defined runtime attributes" section in interface builder. Then in the viewWillAppear block just check the property set by the xib on that instance.

Comment: OK! I think we are almost there however there is one problem. I have this code in the ViewWillAppear: `NSUInteger selectedIndex = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;     NSLog(@"Selected Index: %d", selectedIndex);` When I run the app the index is not consistent. Example: App loads and Tab A shows `Selected Index: 0` in the debugger, clicking tab B shows `Selected Index: 1`, tab C shows `Selected Index: 2`, then clicking tab A should show 0 but shows `Selected Index: 2`, tab B then shows `Selected Index: 0` and so on... This is very strange! Any suggestions?

Comment: Update - I forgot to add the property! Now I have this code in the .h file `@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UITabBarController *tabBarController;`, and the code in my previous comment in the .m file. The result is now an output of `Selected Index: 0` for each Tab - In other words they all product a 0... Any Suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm. That would appear to be a race condition where the view is told it will appear before the tab bar controller's selection is changed. I have verified that this also happens on the device. As it works correctly the first time (and presumably you only need to configure the class the first time) you can store a BOOL to see if you have done setup before.

Comment: you don't need to add the property. It is inherited from UIViewController

Comment: Jack - your last comment prompted me to do the following two things: 1) remove the @property from the .h file. 2) move the code **out** of the **viewWillAppear** and put it **in** the **viewDidAppear** It now works perfectly! Again, thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Cool. The problem with using viewDidAppear is that it can cause flashes of your UI if you configure when then view is on screen. If it works in your situation then excellent! Ive added some alternative solutions to my answer just in case you come unstuck.

Comment: Update - I will have to research this some more. I forgot that the viewDidAppear is processed after the cellForRowAtIndexPath. I need the detection to happen **before** cellForRowAtIndexPath so that I can prepare the data for the TableView... Once I figure this out I'll post my findings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6939/discussion-between-jackslash-and-cocoanoob)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have many choices:
- you may want to override the `init` method in your m file which I guess initializes a `UITableViewCOntroller` and pass an additional parameter to it depending on which tab you are in.

- you may also want to add a `tabid` property to this class and set that when you are creating it for each tab (to something that shows which tab you are in).
- you mat also use notifications (but it wont be the easiest or best solution, unless you have good reason not to use the first two)
- I am sure there are lots of other ways.

Comment: Ali, yes I was thinking of creating a property to track the tabId or tabName (whatever) however I'm not sure how to "capture" that tab name... Would you be able to supply me with a code example? Thanks in advance!